# Load image to ImageView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I would like to display image(saved in project folder) in dialog window, but when I run my method showDialogWithImage I get FileNotFoundExcpetion: imgs\pic1.jpg (The system cannot find the file specified), although the image is located there.

I have tried load image on this way too:
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));, but got the same problem.

Are there some others possibilities to load image to ImageView ?
Thank you for help!

- My Java code is located in src\myProject\gui in project folder.
- path="imgs\pic1.jpg" // imgs is located in project folder

```java
public void showDialogWithImage(String path) {
        final Stage dialogStage = new Stage();

        logger.info(path);

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(path); // here I get FileNotFoundException
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Image image = new Image(is);
        ImageView view = new ImageView();
        view.setImage(image);

        Button btnOK = new Button("OK");
        btnOK.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                dialogStage.close();
            }
        });

        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(view, btnOK).alignment(Pos.CENTER)
                .padding(new Insets(35)).build()));
        dialogStage.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` will start its file search from the location of the calling class. So by using this path `"imgs\pic1.jpg"`, you're saying this is your file structure

```
src\myProject\gui\imgs\pic1.jpg
```

To have the search traverse back, you need the extra separator before `imgs`. So

```
"\imgs\pic1.jpg"
```

Also, I think when you use a back slash as separator, you need to escape it. So

```
"\\imgs\\pic1.jpg
```

Or just use forward slash

```
"/imgs/pic1.jpg
```

Another option is to use a class loader, that will search from the root, where you don't need the beginning separator

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("imgs/pic1.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

when you load an image with path you need replace seperator file "\" with "/" for example

```
                            String ImageName="MyImage.png";

                            File file = new File("src\\Messages\\Attachements\\Images");

                            try {
                                if (!file.exists()) {
                                    FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);


                                } 

                                }

                            } catch (Exception io) {
                                io.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Image image = new Image("/Messages/Attachements/Images/"+ImageName=);
                            ImageReceived.setImage(image);
```