# Simplest way to add an image in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I don't understand is how to add a simple image. I imported everything and followed what they said on this page:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/LoadajpgimagewithImageanduseImageViewtodisplay.htm

**Javafx code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("HTML");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        VBox root = new VBox();    

        final ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView();   
        Image image1 = new Image(test.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg"));

        selectedImage.setImage(image1);

        root.getChildren().addAll(selectedImage);

        scene.setRoot(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1110)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:694)
    at prototype.test.start(test.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
```

Comment: `test.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg")` returns `null`, did you try using `/` as the documentation specifies?

Answer (score 7):

[`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) tries to load an element in the classpath. It's not meant to load files unless they are included in the classpath. To load a file outside of the classpath, use a [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instead:

```
Image image1 = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg"));
```

Or use the [`Image(String)` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) and pass the `URL` of the file:

```
Image image1 = new Image(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding image to GridPane

```
ImageView img1 = new ImageView(new 
Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg")));
    GridPane.setConstraints(img1, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

As fabian mentioned, [`Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) loads an `InputStream` from the classpath, (meaning, from the jar file itself). To load a file from your computer, you can simply use the `file` protocol and give the path to the `Image` constructor, like so:

```
Image image1 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/x.jpg");
```

The reason that you were getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

in your error is because [`Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) simply returns `null` when it can't find the resource that you tell it to look for. The `Image` constructor was receiving `null` and then throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be this line:

```
Image image1 = new Image(test.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg"));
```

Because you get a NullPointerException: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null`.

See:

- [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix
  it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [Load image to ImageView
  JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744283/load-image-to-imageview-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to fix this is dragging your image to the project folder. That way you can search for the name alone

```
Image image1 = new Image(test.class.getResourceAsStream("x.jpg"));
```

if this does'nt work add File:

Answer (score -1):

`Your problem is at line getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\x.jpg"));`
Replace "\\" to "/", your problem is solved

Comment: Hey, so I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to let you know why someone down-voted this (I might be somewhat wrong myself): the "\\" is used for Windows paths, so this wouldn't have been the problem, unless maybe they were using Mac/Linux. Sorry that your first post was down-voted, but good luck with your future endeavors!